# (Vue.js) card not showing when using v-for directive

Tags: php, vue.js, phpmyadmin

```
<div v-for="form in forms" :key="form.forms.id">
                        <div
                            class="max-w-sm p-6 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                            <span
                                class="text-transparent font-bold bg-clip-text bg-sky-400 text-4xl flex md:justify-end justify-center">{{count(form.response_fields.id)}}</span>
                            <a href="#">
                                <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{{form.form_name}}TEST
                                </h5>
                            </a>
                            <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">You have {{ count(form.response_fields.id) }} pending reviews on this
                                check sheet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is the code for the card.

```
<script setup>
    import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue';

const props = defineProps({
    forms: Array,
});

</script>
```

This is my script setup.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $forms = DB::table('response_fields')
        ->join('forms', 'response_fields.form_id', '=', 'form.id')
        ->select(
            'forms_id',
            'response_fields.id',
            'form_name',
            'response_fields.response',
            'response_fields.status',

        );

        return Inertia::render('Dashboard', [
            'forms' => $forms,
        ]);
    }
```

And this is my controller code.

I am trying to create a card which will dynamically multiply based on how many data there are on my database table. For some reason the card is not showing up on my website. What could be wrong?

Comment: Most likely, `forms` is empty? Impossible to say from the code in the answer